# Show that the additive group of real numbers has infinite index in the additive group of the complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am thinking of giving specific example like let the two group be [a+ib]+[c+id] where a,b,c,d are all real numbers. Considering [a+ib]=[4+6i] and [c+id]=[4+2i] then [a+ib]+[c+id]=[8+8i].

Answer (score 2):

The "quotient" group is infinite, because it is (isomorphic to) the group of all complex numbers of the form $bi$, where $b$ ranges over the reals.